# Can I fit a damper to sr Suntour spring forks?

Tags: mountain-bike, repair, fork, suspension, upgrades

I bought a GT avalanche 3 second hand with seized forks. When I stripped them down to clean, there is a coil spring in one side only and no damper fitted.

Can I buy a sr Suntour damper and fit that to these forks? Should it have come with one?[image: The forks disassembled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The fork doesn’t have a damper and never did.

No. You can’t retrofit a damper to these forks.

Possibly you might be better served with a pair of rigid forks or hit up your LBS to see what they have in the salvaged parts bins.

New 1-1/8 26” forks are available however that’s maybe not a good investment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll probably stick with them as they are, just wondered if there was anything I could do to improve them while I had them apart.